# Disable WebBrowser without graying out

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I set `IsEnabled="False"` for a Web Browser in Windows Phone 8, but it becomes gray instead of white.

Is there any way to prevent graying out for a web browser while setting `IsEnabled` to `false`?

- Please don't tell me that it's a bad thing to do. The web browser must be disabled for a few moments, so a `Pivot` can grab swiping. My app is a hybrid PhoneGap + Native application, and each `PivotItem` contains a `CordovaView` element.

Comment: I'd recommend using the 'disable' flag on your HTML element and using some type of JavaScript to toggle that flag when your page is ready.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Does it allow the Pivot or Panorama to swipe to next page? I think it needs to be disabled in XAML level.

Comment: @Romasz Seems that it works. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use [UIElement.IsHitTestVisible property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.ishittestvisible).

When you set its value to **False** it won't report any input events and cannot receive focus.

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi Is it possible in your case to set Pivot.SelectedIndex property?

Comment: It's a pivot with `WebBrowser`s inside each `PivotItem`. Those webbrowsers only contain vertical scroll items. I need the Pivot to behave naturally. Now, if I set SelectedIndex manually, then swiping effect will not follow user's hand, which is not good.

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi I'm not sure, but in this case there may be a need to add some custom animation following the movement. Maybe try [kidshaw's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26353426/2681948) - I'm not sure how it will behave when upon click event, you overlay webbrovser, will the pivot behave as usual when moving finger (maybe it's easier solution)?

Comment: I ended up implementing custom animations.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling directly, you could overlay a rectangle with a translucent white background. If placed in front of the web browser control it would handle interactions preventing the web browser from being edited and can be made visible by the same binding you currently use to control IsEnabled on the web browser.

If you want to be really helpful, you could use a border with a nested label to display a 'please wait' message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Just change it through the style, like so :

```XAML
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Chubs_WB" TargetType="phone:WebBrowser">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:WebBrowser">
                    <Border x:Name="StateContainer" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Opacity="1">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WebBrowserStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!--
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="StateContainer"/>
                                        -->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="PresentationContainer"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

---

```XAML
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="myBrowser" Style="{StaticResource Chubs_WB}" />
```

We just get rid of the Double Animation on Disabled.